Why does TypeScript fail to infer the correct types in a generic union type function?
I am working with a TypeScript setup where I have a union type representing different connector types, each with its own slug and a set of functions. I want to create a manager that calls a specific function (createClient) based on the provided slug and ensures the correct parameter and return types.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
type connectorA = {
  slug: 'whatsapp'
  createClient: (id: number) => number
  updateClient: (id: number) => number
}

type connectorB = {
  slug: 'messenger'
  createClient: (id: string) => string
  updateClient: (id: string) => string
}

type allConnectorTypes = connectorA | connectorB
type allConnectorSlugs = allConnectorTypes['slug']
type allFunctionNames = Exclude<keyof allConnectorTypes, 'slug'>

type getConnectorType<
    T extends allConnectorSlugs
> = Extract<allConnectorTypes, { slug: T }>
type getFunctionType<T extends allConnectorTypes, S extends allFunctionNames> = S extends keyof T ? T[S] : never
type getFunctionFirstParameterType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (arg1: infer P, ...args: any) => any ? P : never
type getFunctionReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer P ? P : never

type helper1<T extends allConnectorSlugs, S extends allFunctionNames> = getFunctionFirstParameterType<getFunctionType<getConnectorType<T>, S>>
type helper2<T extends allConnectorSlugs, S extends allFunctionNames> = getFunctionReturnType<getFunctionType<getConnectorType<T>, S>>

type TManager = {
  createClient<S extends allConnectorSlugs, C extends allFunctionNames>(connectorSlug: S, data: helper1<S, C>): helper2<S, C>
}

const manager: TManager = {
  createClient(connectorSlug, data) { // this function fails
    // ! How to implement here ?
    if (connectorSlug === 'messenger') {
      return data
      // cant see type of data
    } else if (connectorSlug === 'whatsapp') {
      // ! cant see type of data
      return data
    }
  },
}

Error:
[{
    "resource": "Untitled-2",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2322",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Type '<S extends allConnectorSlugs, C extends allFunctionNames>(connectorSlug: S, data: getFunctionFirstParameterType<getFunctionType<getConnectorType<S>, C>>) => getFunctionFirstParameterType<...> | undefined' is not assignable to type '<S extends allConnectorSlugs, C extends allFunctionNames>(connectorSlug: S, data: getFunctionFirstParameterType<getFunctionType<getConnectorType<S>, C>>) => getFunctionReturnType<...>'.\n  Type 'getFunctionFirstParameterType<getFunctionType<getConnectorType<S>, C>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'getFunctionReturnType<getFunctionType<getConnectorType<S>, C>>'.\n    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'getFunctionReturnType<getFunctionType<getConnectorType<S>, C>>'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 30,
    "startColumn": 3,
    "endLineNumber": 30,
    "endColumn": 15,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 26,
            "startColumn": 3,
            "endLineNumber": 26,
            "endColumn": 126,
            "message": "The expected type comes from property 'createClient' which is declared here on type 'TManager'",
            "resource": "Untitled-2"
        }
    ]
}]

I have a union type representing different connectors, each with a specific slug and associated functions like createClient. I created a generic manager function to handle different slug values and infer the correct parameter and return types based on the provided slug. I expected TypeScript to infer the correct types automatically. However, I encountered type inference issues where TypeScript is unable to match the correct types, resulting in errors. I attempted to use type assertions as a workaround, but I am looking for a more robust solution where TypeScript can infer the types correctly without assertions.

There is a problem in getConnectorType:
type getConnectorType<
    T extends allConnectorSlugs
> = allConnectorTypes extends { slug: T } ? allConnectorTypes : never

When true, you return allConnectorTypes, which is connectorA | connectorB, so you are not selecting one of the two connectorA or connectorB. You always return both.
The following is probably what you want:
type getConnectorType<
    T extends allConnectorSlugs
> = Extract<allConnectorTypes, { slug: T }>

Then you need a casting in your function createClient:
const manager: TManager = {
  createClient<
    S extends allConnectorSlugs, 
    C extends allFunctionNames
  >(connectorSlug: S, data: helper1<S, C>) { // this function fails
    if (connectorSlug === 'messenger') {
      return data as helper2<S, C>; // <-- Added casting
    } else if (connectorSlug === 'whatsapp') {
      return data as helper2<S, C>; // <-- Added casting
    } else { // <-- Added else
      throw new Error(`Unsupoerted connectorSlug ${connectorSlug}`);
    }
  },
}

Inside this function you will not be able to see the type of data. The parameter data will be helper1<S, C> because while you define the. function TypeScript doesn't know if S will be messenger or whatsapp.
The above seems to work fine:
const r1 = manager.createClient('messenger', 1); // Error (r1 is string)
const r2 = manager.createClient('messenger', "1"); // OK (r2 is string)
const r3 = manager.createClient('whatsapp', 1); // OK (r3 is number)
const r4 = manager.createClient('whatsapp', "1"); // Error (r4 is number)

Update (Alternative implementation with no casting)
Here is a different implementation that works around the typescript limitations around generics mixed with discriminated unions and control flow analysis.
type FirstParameterType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (arg1: infer P, ...args: any) => any ? P : never;

type Client<T> = {
  createClient: (id: T) => T;
  updateClient: (id: T) => T;
}

type ClientMethods = keyof Client<any>;

type Clients = {
  messenger: Client<string>;
  whatsapp: Client<number>;
};

type ClientNames = keyof Clients;;

type Data<T extends ClientNames, F extends ClientMethods> = FirstParameterType<Clients[T][F]>;

const manager = {
  createClient<
    S extends ClientNames, 
    C extends ClientMethods
  >(connectorSlug: S, data: Data<S, C>) {
    if (connectorSlug === 'messenger') {
      return data;
    } else if (connectorSlug === 'whatsapp') {
      return data;
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Unsupoerted connectorSlug ${connectorSlug}`);
    }
  },
}

manager.createClient('messenger', 1); // Error
manager.createClient('messenger', "1"); // OK
manager.createClient('whatsapp', 1);  // OK
manager.createClient('whatsapp', "1");  // Error

Playground demo

Thank you for pointing out the issue with getConnectorType; I simplified it incorrectly in my question. Your correction is what I intended.
However, I noticed that in your solution, you redefined the generic types and used type casting. Since TManager already defines these, I expected TypeScript to infer them automatically. Using type assertions seems to defeat the purpose of type safety. Is there a way to achieve this without re-declaring the types or using casting?

Some limitations in TS cause the issues you are seeing. I have added a very different implementation that works around the limitations so the casting is not required.
